# Thousands of packages to update

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, kde, software-updates

Normally I use `aptitude upgrade` or `aptitude full-upgrade` to get my system up to date.  Since I am fiddling around with Vbox installation, I followed *https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox* strictly and added  `deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and ran `apt update`, which apparently gives much more information about the installation process than `aptitude` including a lot of Error messages.  So I started fixing these (e.g. NO_PUBKEY, superfluous cdrom entries, etc.).  While searching the web to solve a few issues, I see the plasma update icon "Updates available" popping up.  Okay, taking a look ... it shows "2584 packages to update" with more than 2 GiB to download ... and the count and volume are steadily growing as I write this question!

All seem to be not system relevant, just applications like Activity Pager, Akregator, and so on which I don't remember to have ever installed.

What did I do wrong?  How to fix this?  And why do I get updates for packages I don't recall to have ever installed?

I am running Debian Buster with KDE Plasma.

UPDATE: if the Sid line in *sources.list* is commented out, then the update request disappears;  however something starts downloading from the internet (not sure yet what and why) whenever the network is connected

Comment: You’re not following the right instructions for your release. You need to follow [the instructions for Debian 10](https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Debian_10_.22Buster.22).

Comment: I didn't think of `sid` as a release, but more of a specification for `buster` (like free=/=non-free, stable=/=unstable).  But you are right and I guess I should not compromise my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `sid` to your `sources.list` will upgrade all the packages from debian buster to `sid` (the development branch).

If you need to stay stable, remove the following line from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

Then run :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

[Can I use Sid packages on "stable" or "testing"?](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable#Can_I_use_Sid_packages_on_.22stable.22_or_.22testing.22.3F)

> **Trying to do so is highly discouraged**. Attempting to mix packages between Debian repositories will likely create an unusable system. For more information about best practices, check out [DontBreakDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian).

> If you wish to use newer software, it is best to install packages from Backports.

Answer the question update: After commenting the SID repository `apt` will download the package index based on `/etc/apt/sources.list`, it will be used later to upgrade the packages.

Answer the comment: So this is a "one time" event? As I like to run Vbox on my machine, I guess I should upgrade to Sid -- or does it get very unstable?

To install virtual box in debian buster see the [instruction here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads):

Add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian buster contrib
```

then:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1
```

Adding Sid to stable will make your system unstable and my lead to a broken packages, it will be hard to find the system stability. See [SystemDowngrade](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemDowngrade).

If you need to migrate to unstable, edit your `sources.list`, use only the following line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

then run:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

[DebianUnstable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable)

Comment: So this is a "one time" event?  As I like to run Vbox on my machine, I guess I should upgrade to Sid -- or does it get very  unstable?

Comment: You can upgrade the debian os but you can't downgrade the debian os - you have to do a new install in order to downgrade.

Comment: After I added sid to _sources.list_, I ran `apt update`, but as this was immediately afterwards not much was updated and I started to work on the error messages.  So I think my system is still "stable" or "buster" and not "sid".  However, I am tempted to try sid hoping that vbox will work.

Comment: @I'mnotabug--I'mafeature see my edit please.

Comment: @GAD3R - Thanks! Backports is the way to go and not sid (at least in my case).